# Error in Stepwise regression: Error in terms.default(object) : no terms component nor attribute"

Tags: r

I am working on a stepwise regression but am running into an error at the forward step:

```
Error in terms.default(object) : no terms component nor attribute
```

And I am not sure what to do about it.

Here is my code:

```
FullModel <- glm(Disease ~ age2 + Race2 + Gender + Lab1+ Lab2 + Lab3 + Lab4 +Lab5 + Lab6 + Lab7, family=binomial, data=Data)

EmptyModel <- glm(Disease ~ 1, family=binomial, data=Data)

Data<-na.omit(Data)
backwards = step(FullModel) 
formula(backwards)

Data$forwards <- step(Data$EmptyModel,scope=list(lower=Data$EmptyModel,upper=Data$FullModel), direction="forward")
```

Error:

```
terms.default(object) : no terms component nor attribute
```

To trouble shoot, I checked to make sure that the class of the objects used were correct:

```
> class(EmptyModel)
[1] "glm" "lm" 
> class(FullModel)
[1] "glm" "lm"
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you kindly, in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `forwards <- step(EmptyModel,scope=list(lower=~1,upper=formula(FullModel)), direction="forward")` .. ?

Comment: By replacing the "EmptyModel" with 1, I get the same error:                        Error in terms.default(object) : no terms component nor attribute

Comment: `EmptyModel` has to be a fitted model ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the documentation carefully - this is admittedly not easy.

> scope: defines the range of models examined in the stepwise search.
>             This should be either a single formula, or a list containing
>             components ‘upper’ and ‘lower’, both formulae.  See the
>             details for how to specify the formulae and how they are
>             used.
>
> The set of models searched is determined by the ‘scope’ argument.
>        The right-hand-side of its ‘lower’ component is always included in
>        the model, and right-hand-side of the model is included in the
>        ‘upper’ component.  If ‘scope’ is a single formula, it specifies
>        the ‘upper’ component, and the ‘lower’ model is empty.  If ‘scope’
>        is missing, the initial model is used as the ‘upper’ model.
>
> Models specified by ‘scope’ can be templates to update ‘object’ as
>        used by ‘update.formula’.  So using ‘.’ in a ‘scope’ formula means
>        ‘what is already there’, with ‘.^2’ indicating all interactions of
>        existing terms.

This means that the elements of scope must be **formulas** (or "formulae" if your prefer ...)

So if you had a full additive model:

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(y=rbinom(100,size=1,prob=0.5),
                x1=rnorm(100),
                x2=rnorm(100),
                x3=rnorm(100),
                x4=rnorm(100))
FullModel <- glm(y ~ x1+x2+x3+x4, family=binomial, data=dd)         
EmptyModel <- update(FullModel, . ~ 1)
```

Since I made up random data, the stepwise procedure throws everything away ...

```
backwards = step(FullModel) 
formula(backwards)  ## y ~ 1
```

Forward stepwise regression:

```
forwards = step(EmptyModel, scope=list(lower=.~1,
                                      upper=formula(FullModel)),
               direction="forward")
```

Forward stepwise regression also ends up with the trivial model.

```
formula(forwards) ## y ~ 1
```

As a shortcut, if you want an additive model including all of the variables in the data except the response, you can just use `glm(y~. , ...)`; this also works as a formula in the `scope` argument (as described in the documentation)